# i am trying to use regex in my validation code but do not know where to put it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

i am trying to use regex in my validation code but do not know where to put it?

My regex validation is for first name, last name, email address and password.

I have put validation on first and last name but it's not working.

Also, can someone please suggest validation for password fields too? Thank You in advance.

### Here's my code:

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const input = document.querySelectorAll("input");

form.addEventListener("submit",e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(e)
    
    const firstName = form.firstName.value.trim();
    const lastName = form.lastName.value.trim();
    const email = form.email.value.trim();
    const password = form.password.value.trim();
    const nameReg = /^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]+$/u;
    const emailReg =/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*/;
    
    
    if (firstName === "" && lastName === "" && email === "" && password === ""){
        first()
        last()
        mail()
        pass()
        border();
    } else if (lastName === "" && email === "" && password === ""){
        last();
        mail();
        pass();
        border();

    }else if (email === "" && password === ""){
        mail();
        pass();
        border();
    }else if (lastName === "" && email === ""){
        last();
        mail()
        border();
    }
    else if (lastName === "" && password === ""){
        last();
        pass();
    }else if(firstName === "" && lastName === ""){
        first();
        last();
        border();
    }
     else  if (firstName === "" && firstName === nameReg){
         first()
         border();

    } else if (lastName === "" && lastName === nameReg){
        last();
        border();
    } else if (email === ""){
         mail();
         border();
    } else if (password === ""){
        pass();
        border();
    }else{
        form.reset();
    }
})
///First Name Text
const first = () =>{
    document.getElementById("firstImg").style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("firstName").style.display = "block";
    form.firstName.placeholder = "";
}
// Last name Text
const last = () =>{
    document.getElementById("secondImg").style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("secondName").style.display = "block";
    form.lastName.placeholder ="";
}
// Email
const mail = () =>{
    document.getElementById("thirdImg").style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("third").style.display = "block";
    form.email.placeholder = "email@example/com";
    form.email.setAttribute("class","placeholder"); 
}
//Password Text
const pass = () =>{
    document.getElementById("fourthImg").style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("fourth").style.display = "block";
    form.password.placeholder ="";
}
/// Border for the input fields
const border = () =>{
    input.forEach((field)=>{
        if(field.value === ""){
            field.style.border ="2px solid hsl(0, 100%, 74%)";
        } else{
            field.style.border= "1px solid black";
        }
    }
)};
```

```css
*,
*:focus,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-image:url(../images/bg-intro-desktop.png);
    background-color:  hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 40%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.h2{
    color: white;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-size: 3.2em;
}
.paragraph{
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
#firstH2{
    margin-bottom: -14px;
}
.box{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 9px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.firstButton{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: hsl(248, 32%, 49%);
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 9px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-weight: bolder; 
}
.firstButton span{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
input {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 1px solid hsl(246, 25%, 77%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color:  hsl(249, 10%, 26%);
}
input:focus{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color:  hsl(249, 10%, 26%);
}
input::placeholder{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.placeholder::placeholder{
    color: hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
}
#greenButton{
    width: 90%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: hsl(154, 59%, 51%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px hsl(154, 65%, 43%);
}
#greenButton span{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#greenButton:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: hsl(154, 94%, 65%);
}
.terms{
    color: hsl(246, 25%, 77%);
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}
.terms span a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
    font-weight: bold;
}
form{
    position: relative;
}
#firstImg{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13%;
    right: 9%;
}
#secondImg{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 29%;
    right: 9%;
}
#thirdImg{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: 9%;
    
}
#fourthImg{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 33.5%;
    right: 9%;
}
.errorMessage{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
    text-align: right;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
#firstName{
    display: none;
}
#secondName{
    display: none;
}
#third{
    display: none;
}
#fourth{
    display: none;
}
.attribution{
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.attribution a {
    color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width:700px){
    body{
        background-image:url(../images/bg-intro-mobile.png);
    }
    .grid{
        grid-template-columns: 90%;
    }
    .h2,.paragraph{
        text-align: center;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Intro component With Sign up Form</title>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
       <!-- 1st grid -->
        <div>
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
          <h2 class="h2" id="firstH2">Learn to code by</h2>
          <h2 class="h2">watching others</h2><br>
          <p class="paragraph">See how experienced solve problems in real time. Watching scripted tutuorials is great, but 
            understanding how developers think is invaluable.</p>
        </div>
         <!-- 2nd grid -->
        <div>
          <div>
            <br><br>
            <button class="firstButton">Try it free 7 days <span>then $20/mo. thereafter</span></button>
            <br><br>
            <!-- box for white color -->
            <div class="box">
              <form>
                <br><br>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" id="firstImg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage" id="firstName">First Name cannot be empty</div>

                <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" id="secondImg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage" id="secondName">Last Name cannot be empty</div>

                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" id="thirdImg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage" id="third">Looks like this is not an email</div>

                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" id="fourthImg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage" id="fourth">Password cannot be empty</div>

                <button type="submit" id="greenButton"><span>CLAIM YOUR FREE TRIAL</span></button><br>

                <div class="terms">
                  By clicking the button you are agreeing to our <span><a href="#">Terms and Services</a></span>
                </div><br><br>
              </form>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <br><br>
  <footer>
    <p class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
      Coded by <a href="#">Gurkiran Singh</a>.
    </p>
  </footer>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurkiran/o3mz2kt7/)

Comment: You have a script include for ` <script src="js/script.js"></script>`  which isn't going to work in a sandbox.  What is in that file?

Comment: You are making life unnecessarily difficult for yourself: the `<input type="email">` field will already check the input for a suitable email syntax. There is no need to repeat it with your own regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Corona-times type answer: I had so much time on my hands that I sat down and tried to rework your example.

My first impression: you should try not to repeart yourself ("DRY" : Don't Repeat Yourself). THis applies to both your HTML as to your JavaScript. I removed quite a few of your IDs as they will make scripting only harder and more verbose. Instead I tried to analyse the structure of your HTML. I first scan through your form and collect all input fields, image tags and divs into an array called `inps`. This is done by
creating a "proper" Array by applying `[... <nodelist>]` on the node list I receive from the `document.querySelectorAll()` call, filtering out all

- `<input>`
- `<img>`
- and all elements with `class="errorMessage"`

I then apply the `.reduce()` method on this array to create another one (`inps`, an array of objects), into which

- I firstly place the object `{inp:el}` containing the `<input>` element and after that
- I then extend this "latest" object (`a[a.length-1]`) with further properties (`img` and `div`) containing the  error-`<img>` and the error-message-`<div>`.
  (Caution: this will only work properly, if there *is* an associated image and an error message div in the HTML for each `<input>` field!)

Triggered by the `submit`-event I then walk trough this carefully prepared (`inps`) array, check the contents of the collected input field and do the necessary actions on the associated images and divs. Inside the `inps.forEach(e=>...)` call I can access each input element with `e.inp` and its associated error image and error div with `e.img` and `e.div`.

As mentioned before, this has been a "Corona times type exercise" for me to show that it is possible with relatively short code but I strongly recommend using the really good HTML5 methods available (using `minlength` and the proper `type`s for the input elements!).

```js
const frm=document.forms[0]; 
const inps=[...frm.querySelectorAll('input,img,.errorMessage')].reduce((a,el,i)=>{
   if (i%3==0) a.push({inp:el});
   else a[a.length-1][el.tagName.toLocaleLowerCase()]=el;
   return a;
 },[])
// the following is superfluous, as it will always test as positive for <input type="email">:
const emailRX =/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*/;

frm.onsubmit=(ev)=>{
 let err,allerrs=0 
 inps.forEach(e=>{
   allerrs+=err=e.inp.value==''? 1 : e.inp.name=="email" ? ( emailRX.test(e.inp.value) ? 0 : 2 ) : 0;
   e.img.style.display=['none','initial','initial'][err];
   e.div.textContent=['',e.inp.placeholder+' must be filled!','Email appears to be invalid'][err];
 })
 return allerrs==0;
}
```

```css
*,
*:focus,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background-image:url(../images/bg-intro-desktop.png);
    background-color:  hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 40%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.h2{
    color: white;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-size: 3.2em;
}
.paragraph{
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
#firstH2{
    margin-bottom: -14px;
}
.box{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 9px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.firstButton{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    background-color: hsl(248, 32%, 49%);
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 9px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-weight: bolder; 
}
.firstButton span{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
input {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 1px solid hsl(246, 25%, 77%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color:  hsl(249, 10%, 26%);
}
input:focus{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color:  hsl(249, 10%, 26%);
}
input::placeholder{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.placeholder::placeholder{
    color: hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
}
#greenButton{
    width: 90%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: hsl(154, 59%, 51%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px hsl(154, 65%, 43%);
}
#greenButton span{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#greenButton:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: hsl(154, 94%, 65%);
}
.terms{
    color: hsl(246, 25%, 77%);
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}
.terms span a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
    font-weight: bold;
}
form{
    position: relative;
}
.errorMessage{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: hsl(0, 100%, 74%);
    text-align: right;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
form img {display:none} /* hide all error-img first ... */
.attribution{
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.attribution a {
    color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width:700px){
    body{
        background-image:url(../images/bg-intro-mobile.png);
    }
    .grid{
        grid-template-columns: 90%;
    }
    .h2,.paragraph{
        text-align: center;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Intro component With Sign up Form</title>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
       <!-- 1st grid -->
        <div>
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
          <h2 class="h2" id="firstH2">Learn to code by</h2>
          <h2 class="h2">watching others</h2><br>
          <p class="paragraph">See how experienced solve problems in real time. Watching scripted tutuorials is great, but understanding how developers think is invaluable.</p>
        </div>
         <!-- 2nd grid -->
        <div>
          <div>
            <br><br>
            <button class="firstButton">Try it free 7 days <span>then $20/mo. thereafter</span></button>
            <br><br>
            <!-- box for white color -->
            <div class="box">
              <form>
                <br><br>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" minlength="3"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage"></div>

                <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" minlength="3"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage"></div>

                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage"></div>

                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
                <img src="../images/icon-error.svg" alt="error">
                <div class="errorMessage"></div>

                <button type="submit" id="greenButton"><span>CLAIM YOUR FREE TRIAL</span></button><br>

                <div class="terms">
                  By clicking the button you are agreeing to our <span><a href="#">Terms and Services</a></span>
                </div><br><br>
              </form>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <br><br>
  <footer>
    <p class="attribution">
      Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
      Coded by <a href="#">Gurkiran Singh</a>.
    </p>
  </footer>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like how you make my code short and clean but how to make to work on input fields of first and last name using regex when user put characters less than 3 and sumits and I want to show the error at the that time too .

Comment: You *could* introduce another check, close to where I put the email regexp test, but it would make much more sense to use the `minlength` attribute in the input fields instead, as I have done in my edited post.

Comment: Can you please explain your code on reduce method. I cannot understand it ?

Comment: I edited my answer yesterday and put in some explanation about the `.reduce()` expression too. Hope that is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use test() function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

In your case you can try:

```
if ( emailReg.test(email) ) {
    // correct email
} else {
    // wrong email
}
```